# How would I make only one tab open at a time in this accordion?

Tags: accordion

The original accordion is from the W3schools site. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp.

I am trying to figure out how to only have one tab open a time? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
     } else {
       panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
     } 
   });
 }
```

Comment: Figured it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    for(var it of elems) {
      it.classList.remove("active");
      it.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }

    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      this.nextUntil().addClass( "close" );
    } 
  });

}
```